# Import PDF file in Angular 7

Tags: angular, pdf

I use `pdf-lib` in my Angular project.

In React to load a pdf file from the file system i do this:

```
import pdfBase from './myFile.pdf'
[....]
// load my document
const existingPdfBytes = await fetch(pdfBase).then(res => res.arrayBuffer())
const pdfDoc = await PDFDocument.load(existingPdfBytes)
```

When I do this in Angular:

```
import pdfBase from 'src/assets/pdf/myFile.pdf';
```

> Cannot find module 'src/assets/pdf/certificat.pdf'.ts(2307)

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: What is your aim with pdf file?

Comment: @Çağrı 
to be able to change it later